# Different Sha1 checksum of image in c#

Tags: c#, sha1

I am creating a sha1 checksum of an uploaded image, my aim is then to compare this with the sha1 checksum of the same image coming from a third party.

My code is returning a successful hex, but it is different to the checksum being sent.  I have tested this using an online converter at: http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator; the hex returned by this converter is the same as that being returned by the third party.

Obviously I am missing a step somewhere but I cannot think what.  I am reading the file with:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
return ms.ToArray();
```

I am then trying to hex this array with:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(image)).Replace("-", "");
```

I have also tried converting the stream before it is turned to an array.

How can I get the same result as the converter at http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator?

Comment: you are re-saving the image which most likely producing different stream as one you are getting in... hence hash difference.

Comment: So how can I do this then?  From every example I have seen of converting an image to byte[], the image needs to be converted/resaved as some format or another.  even resaving as lossless like bmp gives a different hash.

Comment: Do you really start with an image? I strongly doubt that, but if it is true than you are essentially out of luck... If not - just get hash of incoming byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Alexei Levenkov, You were right.  I was being passed an image that appears to have already had some converting done to it.  I get the same checksum if I create the array from the original filepath:

```
e.g.
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(originalFilePath);
```

Now I just have to hope that I always have access to this path in the final implementation.